# Access listed grain values

Tags: salt-stack

I'm trying to access listed grain values from state file, need help on this.

State file is as below

```
{% set list = grains['selinux'] %}

echo {{ list }}:
  cmd.run
```

But when i run the state file got the error.

```
# salt '*' state.sls list_grains
client1:
    Data failed to compile:
----------
    Rendering SLS 'base:list_grains' failed: mapping values are not allowed in this context
ERROR: Minions returned with non-zero exit code
[root@server ~]# vim /srv/salt/list_grains.sls
```

grain values accessed are as below

```
# salt '*' grains.item selinux
client1:
    ----------
    selinux:
        ----------
        enabled:
            True
        enforced:
            Permissive
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `selinux` grain is a dictionary/map like:

```yaml
selinux:
  enabled: True
  enforced: Permissive
```

So in a state ID you cannot have dictionary/map. You can pick the required dictionary key like `list.enabled` or `list.enforced`.

For example, the below state ID will output `Permissive`:

```
{% set list = grains['selinux'] %}

echo {{ list.enforced }}:
  cmd.run
```

If you want to get the complete dict as output, you can use a module like `test.echo`:

```
{% set list = grains['selinux'] %}

show-selinux-grains:
  module.run:
    - name: test.echo
    - text: "{{ list }}"
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply and it worked like a gem but I'm looking to feed the output of `selinux` grain into a variable and use **for loop** to iterate over them to match a string.

Comment: It will more apt to have this requirement stated in the question. You could either update this question, or create a new one. Also add information about what you want to match (achieve) by looping.